# Regex string substitution in file

Tags: python-3.x, regex, logging, substitution

I need to substitute string in file. But no success for now. Any advice is welcome.

I have file output.txt with following content:

```
2021-07-28 10:27:49,869 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:49,881 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:51,834 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following> 
2021-07-28 10:27:52,182 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT <xml code following></xml code following>
```

I have code, which is used for making first par of each line:

```
2021-07-28 10:27:52,182 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT
```

to have:

```
<time>2021-07-28 10:27:52,182 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time>
```

Code follows:

```
regex_time_xml_div = r"\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\s[0-z]{7}\s[0-z]{9}\s.{34}"
            with open(r'output\output.txt',"r+") as file:
                list_of_timestamps = []
                for line in file:
                    if re.search(regex_time_xml_div, str(line)):
                        list_of_timestamps.append(line)
                content = file.read()
                for i in list_of_timestamps:
                    result = re.sub(regex_time_xml_div,'<time>'+i+'</time>',content)
                    print(result,file=open(r'output\output_new.txt',"a"))
```

But as a result file output_new.txt have 4 empty lines. Can anyone please support on this. Thank you in advice.

---

Thanks 4Fingers, I've changed code to:

```
            regex_time_xml_div_1 = r"^"
            regex_time_xml_div_2 = r"\s<"
            xml_time_1 = '<time>'
            xml_time_2 = '</time><'
            with open(r'output\output.txt',"r+") as file:
                for line in file:
                    xml_time = re.sub(regex_time_xml_div_1, xml_time_1, line)      
                    print(xml_time,file=open(r'output\beg_line.txt',"a")) 
            
            with open(r'output\new.txt',"r+") as file:
                for line in file:
                    xml_time = re.sub(regex_time_xml_div_2, xml_time_2, line)
                    print(xml_time,file=open(r'output\after_time.txt',"a"))
```

It is it, now output looks like expected. But the amount of extra files looks a bit confusing. Removed these with os.remove

Comment: Might it have anything todo with the last part of your regex, here you match everything. To be save I would add end and start of line: $ and ^.

Comment: @4Fingers It makes sense, I will test right now. Thank you

Comment: It has worked, thank you very much. The only thing which disturbs right now is amount of created files.

Comment: Great to hear, you might be able to catch all cases in one go with regex `^[a-z0-9\,\-\:\/\s\.]+\<`, dont forget to use case insenstive flag, or add A-Z. Here you assume no < character occurs in the part your trying to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the answer would be:

```
            regex_time_xml_div_1 = r"^"
            regex_time_xml_div_2 = r"\s<"
            xml_time_1 = '<time>'
            xml_time_2 = '</time><'
            with open(r'output\output.txt',"r+") as file:
                for line in file:
                    xml_time = re.sub(regex_time_xml_div_1, xml_time_1, line)      
                    print(xml_time,file=open(r'output\beg_line.txt',"a")) 
            
            with open(r'output\new.txt',"r+") as file:
                for line in file:
                    xml_time = re.sub(regex_time_xml_div_2, xml_time_2, line)
                    print(xml_time,file=open(r'output\after_time.txt',"a"))
```

Thanks a lot for helping :)